# Android MediaPlayer: Multiple sounds playing at the same time. My code is

Tags: android, audio, parse-platform, media-player

I have searched and researched stackoverflow and google but can't find any answer to MY question. I've found other question and answers but that were related to sounds saved in the app but I'm creating an app which gets data from Parse server, so it gets mp3 files and display these in listview and than when an item is clicked it plays that track. But here comes the problem: When you play a sound and click on another one, the first just doesn't stop and the second starts to play.
I have tried with the following code but it's just not working.
Here's my code:

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                final MediaPlayer scndmediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                scndmediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "First is playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        scndmediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFileURL);
                        scndmediaPlayer.prepare();
                        scndmediaPlayer.start();
                        //soundtoolbar.setTitle(name);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        if (scndmediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            scndmediaPlayer.stop();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "First is starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFileURL);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        soundtoolbar.setTitle(name);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || scndmediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                            scndmediaPlayer.pause();
                            playPause.setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp));
                        } else {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            scndmediaPlayer.start();
                            playPause.setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

I've created 2 mediaplayers with the code above and when user clicks the play button it first checks if any of the player is running.
I'm trying to achieve the following: When user clicks the play button it checks if the (1st) `mediaPlayer` is running or not. If it's running, it has just to stop it and launch (2nd) `scndmediaPlayer` or viceversa... if second is playing it stops that and launch first one. so it will create a loop: 1st is playing? User clicks another button stop first. Launch second. User clicks another button. First is playing? No. Second is playing? Yes. Stop the second and launch the first. 
But can't find where is the problem in my code.
Please help me with this. I'm trying to resolve it from 2 days but I'm unable...
Thanks :)

**EDIT:** I tried using one MediaPlayer and do the following: Check if mediaplayer is playing! No it isn't playing. Start it. User clicks the button again and it stops the mediaplayer and start it with new audioFileUrl. BUT. MediaPlayer is forgetting that it's playing. Seems like it just starts the track and than forget and to check if it's true i set a Toast: when mediaplayer isn't playing the toast shows and it's showing every time I click a track in the list which means it forget that it has a track which is playing...

**EDIT 2:** I managed to do the following: It plays the track. User clicks another track. It stops the mediaplayer but doesn't play the new track. User click once again. It plays the new track. User clicks the new track and the app crashes...

**EDIT 3:** Posting my entire class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

public Button playPause, next, previous;
public Toolbar soundtoolbar;
boolean isPlaying = false;
public MyAdapter(Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("MyClass");
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            return query;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public View getItemView(final ParseObject object, View v, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_audio_files_item, null);
    }
    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    final Button play = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.play);
    playPause = TabFragment1.playPause;
    next = TabFragment1.next;
    previous = TabFragment1.previous;
    soundtoolbar = TabFragment1.soundtoolbar;
    final ParseFile descr = object.getParseFile("audiofile");
    final String name = object.getString("name");
    final String audioFileURL = descr.getUrl();
    final SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingUpPanelLayout = TabFragment1.spanel;
    play.setText(name);
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isPlaying != true) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), name+" is playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFileURL);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            soundtoolbar.setTitle(name);
                            slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            isPlaying = true;
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e4) {
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e5) {
                    e5.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Starting "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFileURL);
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            soundtoolbar.setTitle(name);
                            slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e4) {
                    e4.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e5){
                    e5.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        playPause.setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp));
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        playPause.setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
    return v;
}
}
```

Somebody please help...

Answer (score 0):

i suggest  you to checkout SoundPool . İt ll helps you. And one more , may be you ll put media urls to array or something like this.And use one mediaPlayer By the way, you ll avoid from two mediaPlayer and avoid from memory leak.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with SoundPool so I want to keep using MediaPlayer. I tried using one MediaPlayer and do the following: Check if mediaplayer is playing! No it isn't playing. Start it. User clicks the button again and it stops the mediaplayer and start it with new audioFileUrl. BUT. MediaPlayer is forgetting that it's playing. Seems like it just starts the track and than forget and to check if it's true i set a Toast: when mediaplayer isn't playing the toast shows and it's showing everytime I click a track in the list which means it forget that it has a track which is playing...

Comment: I have faced problems with mediaPlayer similar like you. Then i changed view to my code.May be you ll use a key to store mediaPlayer status, then check it form this.

Comment: Please check my edit 3. I posted my entire class. Maybe now it's much easy to understand...